# How can I periodically delete the contents of a folder ("uploads") related to my flask app on heroku

Tags: heroku, flask

I need to periodically delete files of an uploads folder on heroku in python.

I've tried the heroku scheduler but I am constantly getting a fileNotFound error which I am unable to fix.

```
from flask_script import Manager

from app import app

manager = Manager(app)


@manager.command

def hello():
    folder_path = '/uploads/'

    for file_object in os.listdir(folder_path):

        file_object_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_object)
        if os.path.isfile(file_object_path):
            os.unlink(file_object_path)
        else:
            shutil.rmtree(file_object_path)
```

Comment: How "periodically"? [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), so any changes you make to it will be frequently lost right out of the box. Most users are confused by this, but it might actually be what you want.

Comment: @Chris  Periodically as in "once every hour". I don't really understand how to use the ephemeral system. I just want a folder to empty itself every hour.